# Getting Exception when trying to update record second time in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

We keep user object in session. When we update it first time ( using entityManager.merge( ent )) it works fine; but second time I get following exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.kids.domain.Child#22]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:781)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:766)
```

I am using spring with hibernate & jpa. Spring is injecting EntityManager in DAO. I do understand that if I would do a fresh find() everytime then make all the changes on that object and then merge().. it will work fine.. but in my case I cannot do that.

I also checked that the hashcode of EntityManager used is same both time; i.e same EntityManager instance is getting used both time then why it gives this exception when trying to update a record second time

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I tried lots of things but nothing worked. Even on internet there was no solution. Finally, when I removed version from my entities ( i.e. remove OptimisticLockException support provided by hibernate ).. everything started working fine. Probably , I will try to handle OLE myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you call merge method in the current transaction, hibernate will copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier and returns new manageable entity. You need to work on the manageable entity which is returned by the merge in subsequent operations because this entity has new version than in DB.

Comment: I tried to debug based on this hypothesis; merge does return a new object ( with different hashcode ) but it has same version as the original object. I think version gets updated after commit is invoked ( which is done by spring framework)